# How can I access controllers in EmberJS from different classes (like authenticators)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using an app generated using `ember-cli` with `simple-auth` and I need to access controllers from an `authenticator`.

Comment: You probably don't **need** to do that. Accessing a controller in that manner is probably a bad smell. What is the problem the you are trying to solve?

Comment: After the user logs in, I want to store his object which I receive within the login request itself. So I don't have to do two requests.

Comment: So, I suppose you are using a custom authenticator, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to pass your logged in user data to a controller. Chances are that user data will be used in multiple routes/controllers, so you need a globally available object (Ember Services can solve that use case). Luckily this is already handled by ember simple auth in its **session** object, that is where you want to store user data.

In any controller you should be able to do something like:

```
this.get('session.secure.email'); // version 0.8.X
```

Read about the session here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#the-session That is what you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access some controller within an authenticator, you can use the container from within the authenticator's methods, like so:

```
SimpleAuth.Authenticators.Base.extend({
    authenticate: function() {
        var controller = this.container.lookup('controller:yourControllerName');
        // rest of authentication logic
    }
});
```

But as mentioned, it's better to save the data in the session or even in the store (if you're using ember-data) and retrieve the data from that resource.